# How do I write a byteArray to a specific path

Tags: c#, .net, io, cryptography

I currently have a method which is taking a picture and saving it..
Once saved I call this method to encrypt the file from a string path
but im not sure how to save it.. I wanted to do

```
string path = @"C:/somePath"
```

File.WriteAllBytes(path);

but that doesnt work obv. So how do I properly save a bytearray?

```
string key = GetUniqueKey(32);
byte[] encKey = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key);
byte[] imgBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(path);
byte[] ebytes = encrypt.AESEncrypt(imgBytes, encKey);
File.WriteAllBytes();
```

Comment: Why are you using forward slashes in your path?

Answer (score 0):

If you actually check the parameters it's asking for, you need to provide the bytes as well as the path.

So:

```
string path = @"C:/somePath/somefile.png"
string key = GetUniqueKey(32);
byte[] encKey = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key);
byte[] imgBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(path);
byte[] ebytes = encrypt.AESEncrypt(imgBytes, encKey);
File.WriteAllBytes(path, ebytes);
```

Comment: Oh! Still learning so forgot that I could check the parameters! Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Method's signature is:

```
File.WriteAllBytes(string path, byte[] bytes)
```

Comment: That didnt work, I got alot of "Invalid expression" errors.

Comment: You don't make it clear that this is the _signature_ of the method that needs to be called, rather than the code that would be used to call it.